# How to create new rows based on columns while keeping the index constant?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to this one:

[image]

And I would like to create this dataframe:

[image]

I tried to implement this using `df.melt()` and `df.transpose()` but I did not succeed. Does anyone have any tips for that? I tried some solutions I found here but I guess this problem is slightly different from them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd_wide_to_long()` - [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df,
    stubnames='month',
    i=['id', 'Name', 'City'],
    j='month_num',
    sep='_').rename(columns = {'month':'month_value' ,'month_num': 'month'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks! That's true, now it worked, @HenryEcker.  However, the columns `id`, `Name`, and `City`appear only once, and I would need all the rows filled with these repeated values.

Comment: use `reset_index()` @Goosfrabah

Comment: Thanks, guys! This was an elegant solution!